# Parsing a HTML file for CSS references

Tags: php, css

I have a script which is suppose to collect all the css form a defined url or page.  I have tried everything and for some reason it will not get it to detect linked stylesheets such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/typography.css" />
```

I have tried everything I can think of. This is the code I am using that collects on page css and imports.  Any help adding the link system would be great.

```
function scan($page_content){
    $i = 0;
    if(ereg("<style( *[\n]*.*)>\n*(.\n*)*<\/style>", $page_content)){
        if(preg_match_all("/(@\s*import\s* (url((\"|')?)?((\"|')?)|(\"|'){1}).+(\"|')?\)?)/", $page_content, $ext_stylesheets)){
            foreach($ext_stylesheets[0] as $stylesheet){
                $css_content[$i] = preg_replace("/(@\s*import\s*)|(url\(?((\"|')?))|(\"|'){1}|\)?(\"|')?;|(\s)/", "", $stylesheet);
                $i++;
            }
            $array = 1;
        }
        $inline_notused = $this->check_file($page_content, $page_content);
    }
    else die("No page styles, sorry!".$this->helptext);
}
```

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML... use a DOM parser.

Comment: I believe you could use xPath to parse the DOM rather than regex?

Comment: And if you must use regex, don't use ereg. it's deprecated and will be removed from PHP at some point.

Comment: What do you want the result to be with linked stylesheets? Do you want them to be `@import`ed, or do you want the script to get the contents of the style?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice DOM/XPath way ([**demo**](http://viperpad.com/tY3u69)):

```
function scan($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $path = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodes = $path->query('//style|//link');
    $style = '';
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        if($node->tagName === 'style') {
            $style .= $node->nodeValue;
        } elseif($node->tagName === 'link') {
            $style .= "@import url('{$node->getAttribute('href')}')";
        } else {
            // Invalid
        }
        $style .= PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $style;
}
```

Comment: Kinda looks like you need to parse the `<style>` elements for imports and remove them, rather than including the whole content.

Comment: @cHao Ah, I just looked at the code more closely, and it appears that he wants to get every stylesheet *URL*.